# How to set header for multipart httppost?

Tags: android, web-services, http-post

I am trying  this code to upload image and text on server but with this code i got some error "**content-length header already present**" or if i dont set content lenget then it return "**411 length required**"

Please give me some solutions

this is my code

```
    String url = webserviceURLs.createQuestion+"?token"+OkayUserProfileProps.tocken; 
    try { 
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(); 
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url); 
        httppost.setHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");
        httppost.addHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        byte[] abc = convertImageToByte(Uri.parse(imageName.get(0)));

        InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(abc);
        ContentBody mimePart = new InputStreamBody(in, "file1"); 
        MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity();

        reqEntity.addPart("userquestion[question_id]", new StringBody("2")); 
        reqEntity.addPart("userquestion[looks][0][photo]", mimePart);
        httppost.setEntity(reqEntity);   

        int a=abc.length;
        httppost.setHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_LEN,""+abc.length);

        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost); 
        HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity(); 


        if (resEntity != null) {       
            String retSrc = EntityUtils.toString(resEntity);
            System.out.println("Responce "+retSrc);

        }



        return null;
    } catch (Exception e) { 
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        Log.e("Exception", e.getMessage() + ""); 
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Please give me some solutions

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
entity.addPart("image", new FileBody(new File("your image path"));
```

Comment: with this it is showing 

<html>
<head><title>411 Length Required</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>411 Length Required</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.2.1</center>
</body>
</html>

Comment: use httppost.addHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");

Comment: request.addHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");

Comment: what is request here ?

Comment: request means  httppost

Comment: same error sir .. <html> <head><title>411 Length Required</title></head> <body bgcolor="white"> <center><h1>411 Length Required</h1></center> <hr><center>nginx/1.2.1</center> </body> </html>

Comment: i amtrying this sice two days but no sucess

Comment: Please edit and explain your answer in brief to make it more useful for OP and other readers.